# why md-select-on-focus not working in ios?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I have an input box with the `md-select-on-focus` directive and it's working on the web.  After converting it to an Ionic app, it does not work in iOS even though it works in Android.

I noticed that in the library page of angularjs-material it also doesn't work.  Why?
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.10/demo/input

Example:

```
<input type="number" aria-label='qta omaggio'
       ng-model="ordine_riga.pr_qtaomaggio"
       ng-value="ordine_riga.pr_qtaomaggio" min="0"
       ng-change="calcola_qtaomaggio(ordine, ordine_riga); ordine.modificato = true"
       ng-disabled="ordine_riga.pr_confermato != 0"
       md-select-on-focus>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly can I ask where you placed your input field? Is it in a standard Ionic project? Because it is unclear how you made a web app and then converted it in Ionic. If you can be more clear about this, it would be very helpful!

Secondly Ionic uses Platform Specific Styles to customize components for different platforms (IOS, Android, Windows). The MD class is used for Android and will differ from the other platforms.

You can read about this here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/

Comment: i used ionic v1 with a angularjs project.. but the problem is apple because if try with ipad safari don t work too